# "Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid-good/generate'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on AWS Lambda using nodeJS and have aws-sdk & nanoid-good dependencies in my code. I am facing issue and unable to test my lambda code and getting  error which states

**"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid-good/generate'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
"trace": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid-good/generate'",
"Require stack:",
"- /var/task/index.js",
"- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",**

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.logger = console;
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
const ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' });
var en = require("nanoid-good/locale/en");
var generate = require("nanoid-good/generate")(en);
```

Unable to figure out and what needs to be done to solve it. I am using Visual Studio and terminal to locally install the dependencies and create the zip and then upload the code to AWS Lambda.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please can you try this import 'var generate = require("nanoid-good/generate").nanoid(en);' rather then you have used in ur mention code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try what you mentioned but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Please can you try this import:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.logger = console;

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
const ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' });

var en = require("nanoid-good/locale/en");
var generate = require("nanoid-good/generate").nanoid(en);
```

Documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid-good

Comment: Thanks. I did tried this but it didn't help